# How can I migrate my Palm OS memos over to Simplenote?

Tags: data-transfer, notes, device-migration, simplenote

There's an old PDA/smartphone operating system named "Palm OS". It's included with PalmPilot, Palm, Visor, Tungsten, Zire, Treo, and Centro devices.

One of the apps which comes with a Palm OS device is called "Memo Pad" or "Memos". It synchronizes with desktop PIM software such as Palm Desktop or J-Pilot.

On my Palm Treo, in my Memos app, there are about 2200 memos. They're all plain text. Some of the memos hold dozens of kilobytes of text. In total, my MemosDB-PMem file is 6.5 megabytes. I still use the Memos app regularly.

I think I'd eventually like to migrate all memos over to Android.

Evernote is nice, but as Wikipedia [writes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evernote#Data_loss): "The service has experienced several cases of losing customer data."

Also, the free version of Evernote for Android doesn't work so well during times when you're offline. It works better if you pay for a monthly Evernote Plus subscription.

Finally, I know that Evernote supports file attachments, voice memos, photos, and other bells and whistles. But I don't need these features.

I think I'd rather use Simplenote, which I hear works well for plain-text memos.

How can I migrate my Palm OS memos over to Simplenote?

[Edit: To learn about one possible solution, see my comment below.]

Comment: I theorize that you could use the [Palm Desktop memo importer for Evernote](http://www.maddogsw.com/evernote-utilities/evernote-palm-importer/) and then use [other software](//www.google.com/search?q=evernote+to+simplenote) to move the data to Simplenote. I haven't tried this yet. I wonder how well such a two-step process actually works.

Comment: Quick Google-Fu, so not an answer: [Migrating Palm OS Memos to Android](http://gedakc.users.sourceforge.net/display-doc.php?name=android-file-sync). A quite simplistic approach is also available: [Migrating Palm application data to Android](https://daveinabottle.schweisguth.org/2011/03/15/migrating-palm-application-data-to-android/); though that goes via the (free with donation, and not cloud-based) *Note Everything* app, it might work for others as well.

Comment: @Izzy: Neither of your links will give me cloud-based memos. :) But you're right, they might help others.

Comment: Not only that. Once you got them into a usable format, just feed them to the cloud if that's where you want to have them (I personally don't want some cloud having my data, but prefer to keep control myself; funny to find that second link right now, as *Note Everything* was the very first Android app I spent money on ;) So if you use that approach to generate "plain text memos", why not feeding those to Simplenote then as you wrote it supports plain-text memos? That script in the 2nd link can certainly be adapted to store each note into a separate file, if needed.

Comment: @Izzy: Your method might work; but so might the method I mentioned in my [first comment](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/171953/how-can-i-migrate-my-palm-os-memos-over-to-simplenote#comment220266_171953), above.

Comment: Be careful moving notes/memos to Note everything, it will make difficult to move your data in the future because it has not good export functions. In this page you can find sql for sqlite to move to other apps. https://dapgo.github.io/PIM_Data_Interoperability/